# Exception while converting String to Byte array

Tags: c#, sftp, ssh.net

I am using ssh.net to transfer files through SFTP protocol. I need to validate host key fingerprint as an extra layer of security. For that, I wrote a method to convert the string to byte array to compare as I saved the host key as string in my xml configuration and the SFTP client brings the host key as byte array.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using FsLogger;
using Renci.SshNet;


namespace FsUtils.FileOperations
{
    public class FtpHandler
    {
        public string User { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Server { get; set; }


        public void UploadFileSftp(string sourceFile, string targetDir, string sshHostKeyFingerprint)
        {
            using (var client = new SftpClient(Server, User, Password))
            {
                client.HostKeyReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    byte[] receivedFingerprint = e.FingerPrint;
                    byte[] providedFingerprint = StringToByteArray(sshHostKeyFingerprint);

                    e.CanTrust = receivedFingerprint.SequenceEqual(providedFingerprint);
                };
                try
                {
                    client.Connect();

                    if (client.IsConnected)
                    {
                        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFile))
                        {
                            client.UploadFile(fileStream, targetDir);
                        }
                    }
                    Logging.Info("File uploaded successfully");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logging.Error($"Exception occurred - {ex.Message}");
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (client.IsConnected)
                        client.Disconnect();
                }
            }
        }

        private byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where Sftp uploader method gets called-

```cs
using FsLogger;
using FsUtils.FileOperations;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace FsFtpImport
{
    public class FtpImporter
    {
        public FtpImportConfig Config { get; set; }
        private FtpHandler ftpHandler;

        public void Start()
        {
            if (Config == null)
            {
                Logging.Info("Config not found (NULL)");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                ftpHandler = new FtpHandler
                {
                    User = Config.FtpUser,
                    Password = Config.FtpPassword,
                    Server = Config.FtpServer,
                };

                foreach (FolderMapping folderMap in Config.FolderMappings)
                {
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderMap.ClientDirectory);

                    foreach (string file in files)
                    {
                        Uploadfile(file, folderMap.FtpDirectory,Config.SshHostKeyFingerprint);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.Exception(ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            }
        }

        private void Uploadfile(string file, string targetdir,string fingerprint)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (Config.Protocol)
                {
                    case FtpProtocol.Sftp:
                    {
                        this.ftpHandler.UploadFileSftp(file, targetdir,fingerprint);
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        Logging.Error("unknown protocol");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (Config.DeleteSourceFiles)
                    File.Delete(file);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.Error($"Error uploading file {file}");
                Logging.Exception(ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                Logging.Info("File skipped");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is while converting my string host key to byte array, it throws exception.

`<![LOG[Failed: Exception occurred - Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string.]LOG]!>`

I collected the host key from the knwon-hosts file and copied the key along with its encryption algorithm. It looks like this-

`ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBP4cDyvxP/kbZ1XrPxxyMshbTtrY605xu5VL37uZt9mv7d2ZqD3TSWoEcUgHgtzGuRzkGTfDXdT9J=`

How to validate the host key fingerprint without any issues? I greatly appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Code that is shown in the post is *very unlikely* to produce the exception shown at the place you claim it to happen. Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and make sure to inline all necessary data as constants in the code (and indeed verify that the exception is happening, update error message if necessary)

Comment: Also consider to show at least some value that resembles hex encoding of a byte array (it is unclear how that Base64 string is related to the post).

Comment: It sounds to me like the string that is being received is not a hexadecimal string. I suggest logging it in your program and taking a look at it to make sure it is what you are expecting. Note: Base64 != hexadecimal!!!!

Comment: What you posted is a key file with the algorithm name in the first line and a BASE64 string in the second. You can convert BASE64 to a byte array with [Convert.FromBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=net-7.0). Make sure you only try to decode the *second* line

Comment: I removed the first part (algorithm) of the host key and now the exception is changed to-<![LOG[Failed: Exception occurred - Key exchange negotiation failed.]LOG]!>